# Control the number of results from a Magento API call

Tags: php, api, magento

I have a program that we use to connect our Magento store to our back end Inventory Control system via the API. Currently what it does is query the Magento API for all orders in Pending status, inserts them into the back end system, then sets their status to Processing in Magento. Due to limitations on our Inventory system, we can only insert a limited number of orders at a time. We control this by running the whole process through an if loop as shown below (FYI, code has been edited down to show only the key parts of this problem):

```
//The maximum number of orders to download
$iMaxCount = 10 ;

try {
  $proxy = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

$sessionId = $proxy->login($login, $password);

//fetch the pending orders from the site
$field = array(array('status'=>array( 'pending') ));
$arr = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.list', $field);
$iCnt = 0;

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
//only down up to the max count
if ($iCnt < $iMaxCount) {

[... Do the updating and insertion part of the program ...]

   $iCnt++;
} //End of looping through orders
```

The obvious downfall of doing it this way is I still have to pull all Pending orders even though I am going to be working with only 10 of them. i.e. If I have 200 pending orders, the API returns all 200 of them, processes 10, then skips the rest. What I want to do is modify the filter of the API call to pull only 10 orders at a time of status Processing. This would allow me to remove the if loop overhead and make the program run more efficiently because it only gets the data it needs.

Does anyone know how to apply that type of filter? Everything I have seen suggest you can only do this if you know the order numbers and set limits based on that. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: +1 for a clearly phrased question.

Comment: I believe this question was already solved, but it worth to mention that Magento's REST API supports pagination and limit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All API calls are, eventually, just executed PHP code.  There will be a single PHP method somewhere that accepts the arguments passed in via the API call, so your best bet is to track down where that PHP code is executed.

Step 1 is to find the API call's configuration.  In modern versions of Magento, API configurations are kept in files named `api.xml`

```
$ find app/code/core/Mage/ -name 'api.xml'
app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Directory/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/Mage/GiftMessage/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml
```

Once you've found all the `api.xml` files, search through them to fine which one configures your "top level api namespace" (unsure what this is really called by the internal developers)

```
$ find app/code/core/Mage/ -name 'api.xml' | xargs grep sales_order
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            <sales_order translate="title" module="sales">
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            </sales_order>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            <sales_order_shipment>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            </sales_order_shipment>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            <sales_order_invoice>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            </sales_order_invoice>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            <order>sales_order</order>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            <order_shipment>sales_order_shipment</order_shipment>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml:            <order_invoice>sales_order_invoice</order_invoice>
```

It looks like `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml` is the file we want, since it has a `<sales_order />` tag.  Next, open the file and look at the `<sales_order />` node.

```
<sales_order translate="title" module="sales">
    <model>sales/order_api</model>
    <title>Order API</title>
    <acl>sales/order</acl>
    <methods>
        <list translate="title" module="sales">
            <title>Retrieve list of orders by filters</title>
            <method>items</method>
            <acl>sales/order/info</acl>
        </list>
        <info translate="title" module="sales">
            <title>Retrieve order information</title>
            <acl>sales/order/info</acl>
        </info>
```

The first node we're interested in is `<model>sales/order_api</model>`.  This specifies the object that will be instantiated to handle any API call in the `sales_order` namespace.

Next, we're going to look for the method `list` in the `<methods/>` node.

```
<list translate="title" module="sales">
    <title>Retrieve list of orders by filters</title>
    <method>items</method>
    <acl>sales/order/info</acl>
</list>
```

This node tells us that a call to `sales_order.list` corresponds to the method `items`.  Combining that with the information found above, we now know the API call `sales_order.list` will run PHP code equivalent to the following

```
$m = Mage::getModel('sales/order_api');
$results = $m->items($args);
```

Next, open your model file and look at the `items` method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php
public function items($filters = null)
{
    //..a bunch of code to instantiate a collection object..
    if (is_array($filters)) {
        try {
            foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
                if (isset($this->_attributesMap['order'][$field])) {
                    $field = $this->_attributesMap['order'][$field];
                }

                $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }        
}
```

At the end of this method, you can see that the method will run through each argument and attempt to use it as a filter on the collection.  The key is the field, the value is the value search for.  If you inspect the rest of the method you'll see there's no other way the paramaters interact with the collection to add any sort of paging or limits.

So, this leaves you with three options.  The first is to [find a set of values](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections) to pass into

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
```

that will limit your collection.  My suggestion would be some sort of date filter using the `array('from'=>'10','to'=>'20')` syntax.

Your second option would be to create a class rewrite for `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api::items` that does some extra filtering.

Your third option would be to investigate creating a module that adds a custom API method for you to call.

Comment: That's a brilliant 101 on backtracking API methods, Alan. I believe it will be very helpful for many users (at least for the ones really using the search before asking^^). +1 and added to favorites.

Comment: Excellent tutorial, exactly what I needed, and has helped me push this whole problem along to a better solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to set a limit is to locate app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php (and do an overwrite of the class) then:

Change the method signature to accept another parameter $limit so the method signature looks like:

```
public function items($filters = null, $limit = null)
```

Then, add the following line before "foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {":

```
if( $limit ) $orderCollection->setPageSize( $limit );
```

Then simply pass the limit as an extra argument to the sales_order.list api call.

Booyah!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use setPage, which sets the query LIMIT clause by specifying page number (one-indexed) and number of records per page.

```
$collection->setPage($pageNum, $pageSize);
```

To select the second set of 10 items, you would use the following:

```
$collection->setPage(2, 10);
```

More information on this topic can be found here: [Using Collections in Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/using_collections_in_magento)

Comment: The standard Magento Sales_Order API does not allow to pass a limit directly. The OP would need to override `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api::items()` to do so.