# limit number of results using magento API V2

Tags: api, magento, numbers, limit

Hi I have searched the site for my question but haven't found an easy solution and I think the issue is so basic.

I'm using Api V2 so maybe there's a solution now. Here I go, this is my code:

```
$api_soap_url = 'http://localhost/magento/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1';

$client = new SoapClient($api_soap_url);
$session_id = $client->__soapCall('login',array($user, $pw));

$data = array($session_id);
$result = $client->__soapCall('customerCustomerList', $data);
```

This returns all results, I need to limit number of result so I have tried using filters and other solutions found here but no luck.

The only one I haven't tried is  this one:

[Control the number of results from a Magento API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796688/control-the-number-of-results-from-a-magento-api-call)

But filtering by date doesn't solve my problem and rewriting classes is a ver complex solution for such a simple need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've not yet found a way to do this either. I grab a list with just the product number, and walk through each one I **want** to and get the full data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the filter can limit number of result but you can try this:

```
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'created_at',
            'value' => array('key' => 'gt', 'value' => '2012-05-13 06:11:00')
            // where created_at is greater than 2012-05-13 06:11:00
            // For example: eq (equals), neq (not equals), gt (greater than), lt (less than), etc.
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->customerCustomerList($session, $complexFilter);
```

Comment: Is there any way in using API we could literaly implement limit function ?
I am caught up with a type of fetching of orders,where i want the response having 20 Orders each time.As i am using it in Mobile application,the data speed would be limited and if i am fetching some 100-200 Orders at a time,it is taking more time.Best Regards.

Comment: You should using pagination for this case. can be limited by you wanted.

Comment: Yes,but then for pagination,how to create filter in such a way that it would fetch only specific number of Orders(Suppose I wanted to fetch last only 20 Orders). If you know to create the filter in php,then can you share the code here,I would translate it in my Java code.

Comment: You can use $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id)->getProductCollection()->setPageSize($rows)->setCurPage($page)

Comment: I am talking about fetching Orders through using API and that would require a filter,now is there any way to design a filter in such a way that it would fetch only limited number of Orders ?
Please let me know if you don't get my Question.I would provide a breif idea if so.

Comment: +1 @JosuaMarcelChrisano did you ever end up figuring anything out?  I just looked at the code and I'm 99% sure there is no possibility for a limit which is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up overriding **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php**, adding a "special magic" field called "collection.limit". Your mileage may vary; I have tight controls on both the Magento installation and the programs (in this case, a set of C# programs) accessing the Magento installation.

My caller simply uses the "magic field" as a key/ value pair, something like this (please test, again, I was calling from C#, so this php should be considered suspect):

```
$collectionLimitClause = array (
  'key' => 'collection.limit',
  'value' => array('key' => 'eq', 'value' => '10')
);
```

In my Magento installation (this part is tested, live and running), I created a Sales/Model/Order/Api.php in my local namespace and over-rode the items function. Around the 32nd or so line of that function, you'll see this:

```
    $apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
    $filters = $apiHelper->parseFilters($filters, $this->_attributesMap['order']);
    try {
        foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Instead, I "catch" my own magic limiter with the strncmp here, with an if-else inside the foreach:

```
    $apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
    $filters = $apiHelper->parseFilters($filters, $this->_attributesMap['order']);
    try {
        foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
            if( !strncmp($field,"collection.limit",16) ) {
                $orderCollection->getSelect()->limit($value['eq']);
            }
            else {
                $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
```

I'm not overly excited by this, but, I think it's pretty safe and it works.

Comment: By the way, this collection.limit implementation was specifically in response to collect large number of orders from the Magento installation without bogging down everything. So we basically would grab 10 'pending' orders at a time, and continuously process.