# Magento soap api catalog_product.list Pagination

Tags: php, magento, soap, pagination

I’m currently using the Magento api and I need you help guys,

I have 1200 products that I need list in the page… (all products from all categories)

I use

```
 $this->magento_api->call($session,'catalog_product.list');
```

and it’s works as well..
All products is listed.

but now… I got problems because… 1 200 products in 1 page is a little too much..
so I want to know if it’s possible to get… maybe .. 25/50 products
and create a pagination?

thanks for your Help,

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7797226/612717

Basically you have to pass a filter/ComplexFilter specifying `from` and `to` into the returned collection. e.g.

```
$complexFilter->complex_filter = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'CREATED_AT',
        'value' => array('key' => 'from', 'value' => '2012-12-17 00:00:00')
    ), 
    array(
        'key' => 'created_at',
        'value' => array('key' => 'to', 'value' => '2013-01-21 12:02:02')
    ), 
);
```

Of course `CREATED_AT` could also be based on `ID` or any other column in database.

Another fine way to achieve the same is via [GET filters](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/get_filters.html) (assuming you want to pass this control from web). A full blown example using the models and collection methods can also be [found here](http://inchoo.net/magento/pagination-custom-collection/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no answer for this question?

Have you tried `$collection->setPage($pageNum, $pageSize);`

You can also upgrade into **Magento 2.x** now @Jean-philippe Emond

In Magento 2, there will be an option `/V1/products/?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100`